# How to show different <div> in one modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

How can i show (toggle) different divs in one modal? Let me explain:
- when i click on "show me more" i wanna trigger modal (and its working in my case)
- next, i close it (it works)
- i wanna trigger modal again but on different div and offcourse i want this div to be in modal again (now thats where i got stuck at).

Below its snippet of my code...

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close-button">×</span>
                        <div id="wrapper" class="modified">
                        <!-- Main -->
                            <section>
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <h1 class="major">DJ ZA POROKE</h1>
                                    <p align="justify">some text</p>
                                    <p align="justify">some text</p>

                                </div>
                            </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
        var trigger1 = document.querySelector(".trigger1");
        var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

        function toggleModal() {
            modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
        }

        function windowOnClick(event) {
            if (event.target === modal) {
                toggleModal();
            }
        }
        trigger1.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
        closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
        window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

And lets say i trigger it like:

```
<div class="middle">
<div class="text trigger"><a href="#modal">Show me more..</a></div>
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So to get it right:
.

- user clicks a button /other element ("show me more") and a
- modal is shown with content 1
- modal is closed
- user clicks again a button /other element ("show me more") and a
- modal is shown with content 2.
- modal is closed

You have 2 options:

- call two different modals identical except for the content -> this can be done with a state var in JS

  var stateContent = 0;

and check on the button click event in which state we are

- The second more elegant shows/hides the relevant div

HTML addapted

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
                    <div  class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close-button">×</span>
                        <div id="wrapper" class="modified">
                        <!-- Main -->
                            <section>
                                <div id="content_1" class="inner" style="display: block"> <!-- ID added This part is shown -->
                                    <h1 class="major">DJ ZA POROKE</h1>
                                    <p align="justify">some text</p>
                                    <p align="justify">some text</p>
                                </div>
                                  <div id="content_2" class="inner" style="display: none"> <!-- ID added This part is hidden -->
                                    <h1 class="major">XY ZZ POROKE</h1>
                                    <p align="justify">some OTHER text</p>
                                    <p align="justify">some OTHER text</p>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
```

In javascript you change the display style - for simplification I do it on the close button

```
closeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    switchContent();
    toggleModal();
});
```

New function for doing what we want content switching:

```
function switchContent(){
    var content1 = document.getElementById("content_1");
    var content2 = document.getElementById("content_2");
    // Check in which state we are
    if (content1.style.display === 'none') {
        content1.style.display = 'block';
        content2.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            content1.style.display = 'none'; 
            content2.style.display = 'block';       
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for relpay, but it seems problem is elswhere, i cannot trigger modal on <div id="content_2" ...

Comment: trigger modal on <div id="content_2" is not a modal it is just a div, include the code in your original code example and not a new one, and if you need 8 divs you have to use a more or less global state variable to keep track of which div to show.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened editor at w3 so i can show directly what i want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal2</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So you see something went wrong, because when i click OPENMODAL2 it freezes. But anyhow, i want 8 different divs to show in 1 modal.